# How to save a Highcharter plot as an image on local disk?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

```
hc %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "London", data = citytemp$london, type = "area") %>% 
  hc_rm_series(name = "New York")
```

I want to export `hc` as a png or jpg. This can be done by selecting Export - Save as Image but I'd like to do it through codes because I have multiple plots to export. I have tried the followings but it returned a blank image:

```
png('hc.png', width = 800,height = 400)
print(hc)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible with the webshot package (see question here: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/186)

```
library(webshot)
library(highcharter)
library(plyr)

data("citytemp")

plot <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "London", data = citytemp$london, type = "area") %>% 
  hc_rm_series(name = "New York")

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = plot, file = "~/plot.html")
setwd("~")
webshot::webshot(url = "plot.html", 
                 file = "plot.png")
```

Comment: Works great! I noticed that the output image only showed a part of the graph so I set `delay=3` and everything looks good now!