# Insert images into gt table

Tags: r, image, gt

I'm a little confused on how to use the `text_transform` and `local_image` function in the `gt` package to insert images into a data cell

I have a series of about a dozen .png files with the graphics I'd like to insert.  They have names like CA.png, UT.png, OH.png etc. for state abbreviations. They are all together in a local folder.

So given a basic table like

```
library(gt)
library(magrittr)

Column_one <- c("CA", "UT", "OH")
column_two <- c(NA, NA, NA)    #placeholder for graphics

dashboard.data <- data.frame(column_one, column_two, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(dashboard.data)[1] <- "State"
names(dashboard.data)[2] <- "IncidenceGauge"

dboard3 <- dashboard.data %>% gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("**Big Title**"),
    subtitle = md("*Subtitle*")
  ) %>%
  cols_label(IncidenceGauge = "Risk Level") %>%
  
  print(dboard3)
```

How would I go about getting the png files loaded into the corresponding rows in column two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be achieved via `gt` functions `text_transform` and `local_image` like so:

1. As `text_transform` transforms the content of a column put the filenames in your second column.
2. For the function argument `.fn` pass a function to `text_transform` to loop over the column elements, loads and transforms the images via `local_image` and returns a character vector.

Making use of `purrr` and `ggplot2` the following code first makes some example ggplots saves them as png and finally adds them to your second column:

```
library(gt)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

# Let's make some pngs
mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~ ggplot(.x, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(gear))) + geom_point()) %>% 
  set_names(c("CA", "UT", "OH")) %>% 
  iwalk(~ ggsave(paste0(.y, ".png"), .x))

column_one <- c("CA", "UT", "OH")
# Put the filenames in the column
column_two <- c("CA", "UT", "OH")

dashboard.data <- data.frame(column_one, column_two, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(dashboard.data)[1] <- "State"
names(dashboard.data)[2] <- "IncidenceGauge"

dboard3 <- dashboard.data %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("**Big Title**"),
    subtitle = md("*Subtitle*")
  ) %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(vars(IncidenceGauge)),
    fn = function(x) {
      # loop over the elements of the column
      map_chr(x, ~ local_image(
        filename = paste0(.x, ".png"),
        height = 100
      ))
    }) %>% 
  cols_label(IncidenceGauge = "Risk Level")
    
print(dboard3)
```

[image]

Comment: This was great...thanks so much.  Don't suppose you could answer this one? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359096/saving-an-echarts4r-image-via-code-again

Comment: You are welcome. Concerning your second question. I'm afraid I can't help you with that. Actually I already had a look at this question some days ago but wasn't able to find a solution. ): Best S.