# R function for plotting labels and quantitative data in two vertical lines, lines are drawn between those points

Tags: r, data-visualization, echarts, wikidata, parallel-coordinates

## The question

Given this data

```
labels,quantity
string1,20
string2,15
string3,10
string4,19
```

I want to create the following graph in R: Two parallel vertical lines, the one on the left for the labels and the one for the right for the quantitative data. Lines are drawn between the pairs (see image below).

[image]

Is there a function in some R package that can create such plots? If not, could you provide some information on how I could do it?

## Additional context

The graph shown above was generated by Wikidata by using the following SPARQL query ([execute query here](https://w.wiki/5WRa)).

```
#defaultView:Dimensions
SELECT ?a ?b {
   VALUES (?a ?b) {
     ("string1" 20)
     ("string2" 15)
     ("string3" 10)
     ("string4" 19)
   }
}
```

## Data

```r
dat  <- structure(list(labels = c("string4", "string3", "string2", "string1"
), quantity = c(19L, 10L, 15L, 20L)), row.names = 4:1, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this kind of plot with `e_parallel()` in `echarts4r`:

```r
dat  <- dat[order(dat$labels, decreasing = TRUE),]

dat  |>
    e_charts(y  = labels, reorder = FALSE)  |>
    e_parallel(labels, quantity)
```

[image]

It is worth adding that `echarts4r` creates html charts - whether that is a benefit or not depends. You can save it to png using `htmlwidgets` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359096/saving-an-echarts4r-image-via-code-again).